# About "Scipy.optimize"： message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss

Tags: python, scipy

I am implementing threshold regression using SCAD penalty function, SCAD has its own defined derivative, so I also implement the function of SCAD derivative.I pass the derivative to the "optimize"'s jac parameters.
I first used the target function without the SCAD penalty function to give the initial guess, and it can work.
However, when using the penalty function with SCAD to solve the problem, the iterator cannot give correct results, and returns 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'

What shall i do?

```py
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sc
from scipy import stats as st
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize as opt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def loss_SCAD(beta_matrix):
    M_MSE = np.dot(x, beta_matrix[:tmp_lt])[:, None]
    M_c = np.array(beta_matrix[-M:], ndmin=1)
    scad = 0

    for idx, c in enumerate(M_c):
        nor_distri_x = (x[:, 1][:, None] - c) / tmp_h
        nor_distri_CDF = st.norm.cdf(nor_distri_x)  # 光滑示性函数
        M_MSE += np.dot(x, beta_matrix[tmp_lt * (idx + 1):tmp_lt * (idx + 2)])[:, None] * nor_distri_CDF
        beta_param = np.sum(np.abs(beta_matrix[tmp_lt * (idx + 1):tmp_lt * (idx + 2)]))
        if beta_param > a * tmp_lam:
            scad += 0.5 * ((a + 1) * tmp_lam ** 2)
        elif beta_param > tmp_lam:
            scad += ((a ** 2 - 1) * tmp_lam ** 2 - (beta_param - a * tmp_lam) ** 2) / (2 * (a - 1))
        else:
            scad += tmp_lam * beta_param

    MSE = 0.5 * np.average((y - M_MSE) ** 2) + scad
    return MSE


def loss_derivative(beta_matrix):
    deriv_list = []
    other_M_MSE, nor_distri_CDF = 0, 0
    first_M_MSE = y - np.dot(x, beta_matrix[:tmp_lt])[:, None]
    M_c = np.array(beta_matrix[-M:], ndmin=1)

    for idx, c in enumerate(M_c):
        nor_distri_x = (x[:, 1][:, None] - c) / tmp_h
        nor_distri_CDF = st.norm.cdf(nor_distri_x)  # 光滑示性函数
        other_M_MSE += np.dot(x, beta_matrix[tmp_lt * (idx + 1):tmp_lt * (idx + 2)])[:, None] * nor_distri_CDF

    square_part = first_M_MSE - other_M_MSE

    for idx, beta_param in enumerate(beta_matrix[:tmp_lt]):  # 更新梯度：第一段
        deriv_list.append(np.average(square_part * -x[:, idx][:, None]))

    for idx, c in enumerate(M_c):
        beta_param = np.sum(np.abs(beta_matrix[tmp_lt * (idx + 1):tmp_lt * (idx + 2)]))
        if beta_param == 0:  # 更新梯度：SCAD函数
            scad = 0
        elif beta_param > tmp_lam:
            scad = np.max(((a * tmp_lam - beta_param) / (a - 1), 0))
        else:
            scad = tmp_lam
        for i in range(tmp_lt):  # 更新梯度：分段
            deriv_list.append(np.average(square_part * -x[:, i][:, None] * nor_distri_CDF) + scad)

    for idx, c in enumerate(M_c):  # 更新梯度：门槛参数
        nor_distri_PDF = st.norm.pdf((tmp_x - c) / tmp_h)
        deriv_list.append(np.average(square_part * np.dot(x, beta_matrix[tmp_lt * (idx + 1):tmp_lt * (idx + 2)])[:, None] * nor_distri_PDF / tmp_h))

    return np.array(deriv_list)


def loss(beta_matrix):
    M_MSE = np.dot(x, beta_matrix[:tmp_lt])[:, None]
    M_c = np.array(beta_matrix[-M:], ndmin=1)

    for idx, c in enumerate(M_c):
        nor_distri_x = (x[:, 1][:, None] - c) / tmp_h
        nor_distri_CDF = st.norm.cdf(nor_distri_x)  # 光滑示性函数
        M_MSE += np.dot(x, beta_matrix[tmp_lt * (idx + 1):tmp_lt * (idx + 2)])[:, None] * nor_distri_CDF

    MSE = 0.5 * np.average((y - M_MSE) ** 2)
    return MSE


np.random.seed(1171359)
a = 3.7
tmp_x = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=2, size=(400, 1))
tmp_beta = [2, -2, 5, 2, 9, 7]
tmp_c = [-np.sqrt(2), np.sqrt(2)]
M = np.shape(tmp_c)[0]
x1, x2, x3 = tmp_x[tmp_x < tmp_c[0]], tmp_x[(tmp_x >= tmp_c[0]) & (tmp_x < tmp_c[1])], tmp_x[tmp_x >= tmp_c[1]]
y1, y2, y3 = tmp_beta[0] + tmp_beta[1] * x1, tmp_beta[2] + tmp_beta[3] * x2, tmp_beta[4] + tmp_beta[5] * x3
x = np.reshape(np.concatenate((x1, x2, x3)), (-1, 1))
y = np.reshape(np.concatenate((y1, y2, y3)) + np.random.randn(400), (-1, 1))
x = np.concatenate((np.ones_like(x), x), axis=1)
tmp_lt = x.shape[1]
tmp_h = np.log(400) / 400 * tmp_x.std(ddof=1)
tmp_lam = 0.5

tmp_res = opt.minimize(fun=loss, x0=np.append(np.ones(7), 2))
tmp_result = opt.minimize(fun=loss_SCAD, x0=tmp_res.x, jac=loss_derivative)
# print(tmp_result.x, tmp_res.x, sep='\n')

k = tmp_result.x[:-2].reshape((2, -1), order='F')
y_hat_1 = np.dot(x[x[:, 1] < tmp_result.x[-2]], k[:, 0].reshape((-1, 1)))
y_hat_2 = np.dot(x[(x[:, 1] >= tmp_result.x[-2]) & (x[:, 1] < tmp_result.x[-1])], k[:, 0].reshape((-1, 1)) + k[:, 1].reshape((-1, 1)))
y_hat_3 = np.dot(x[x[:, 1] >= tmp_result.x[-1]], k[:, 0].reshape((-1, 1)) + k[:, 1].reshape((-1, 1)) + k[:, 2].reshape((-1, 1)))
print(k, tmp_result.fun, tmp_result, sep='\n')

fig = plt.figure(111, figsize=(6, 6))
plt.plot(x[:, 1][x[:, 1] < tmp_result.x[-2]], y_hat_1, c='orange', alpha=0.6, linewidth=4)
plt.plot(x[:, 1][(x[:, 1] >= tmp_result.x[-2]) & (x[:, 1] < tmp_result.x[-1])], y_hat_2, c='blue', alpha=0.6, linewidth=4)
plt.plot(x[:, 1][x[:, 1] >= tmp_result.x[-1]], y_hat_3, c='green', alpha=0.6, linewidth=4)
plt.plot(x1, y1, c='black', alpha=0.6, linewidth=4)
plt.plot(x2, y2, c='black', alpha=0.6, linewidth=4)
plt.plot(x3, y3, c='black', alpha=0.6, linewidth=4)
plt.scatter(x[:, 1], y, s=12, alpha=0.5, c='gray')
plt.axis([tmp_x.min() * 1.05, tmp_x.max() * 1.05, y.min() * 1.05, y.max() * 1.05])
plt.show()
```

```
fun: 1.6869804934437402
 hess_inv: array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
      jac: array([ 1.98384534e-07, -2.81814249e-07, -1.51727486e-08, -2.17460279e-08,
       -1.51727486e-08, -2.17460279e-08, -1.15503569e+00, -6.99892939e-01])
  message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
     nfev: 84
      nit: 0
     njev: 72
   status: 2
  success: False
        x: array([ 1.93751362, -2.04506983,  3.09129046,  4.13404934,  4.32073797,
        4.87646363, -1.391239  ,  1.4099789 ])
```

Comment: Might be a scaling problem. The magnitude of your jacobian entries is around 10^8, which is usually a bad thing.

Comment: @sascha I don't quite follow you